# Where can I find the format specification for LSLIFF data?

Tags: contour, file-formats, format, specification

I have an **LSLIFF file** which should contain some **map contour data**, and I want to write a renderer for it, but to do that **I need to understand the file format**. A preliminary search has not turned up anything useful.

At first glance my LSLIFF file appears to be some header data followed by some blocks of data (start of block, pairs of points, end of block) followed by footer data, all stored in ASCII.

**What is an LSLIFF file and where can I find the format specification for it?**

The start and end of my file:

```
RA    1252000.0000   1276000.0000   5010000.0000   5046000.0000                 
HI
NS Map sheet CB11 v1-03 created by Translate in Pre-press
NO 1
NF 1 1
FS 26 0 0 0
AC 1021 600.000000
AC 1023 0 ""
AC 1024 0 ""
ST 200 0
1254641.6843 5046000.0000
1254638.9556 5045998.1010

... many more pairs of floating point numbers ...

1271576.5132 5045999.3642
1271575.6188 5046000.0000
EF
NF 12343 12343
FS 26 0 0 0
AC 1021 1500.000000
AC 1023 0 ""
AC 1024 0 ""
ST 5 0
1271618.1602 5046000.0000
1271631.8940 5045958.3569
1271651.0208 5045945.9561
1271663.2206 5045965.9839
1271673.8981 5046000.0000
EF
EO
EM
EJ
```

Comment: There's a little information [here](http://www.linz.govt.nz/topography/topographic-data/technical). Based upon LAMPS software, they call it LSLIFF. Also (may be same as above) [here](http://apps.linz.govt.nz/topo-data-dictionary/document/lsliff-data-format.pdf)

Comment: Ah, yes, it is indeed LSLIFF. My mistake. Thanks, those links (which are pretty much the same info) are a very good start. There are a few fields they do not fully specify but it is miles better than nothing.